# JvmName for overloaded Kotlin property

Tags: java, kotlin, properties, overriding, getter

I have an open Kotlin class with the property of `value: String`.

```
open class PropHolder {
  open val value: String = ""
}
```

There is a Java interface with a function `String getValue()`.

```
public interface Property {
  public String getValue();
}
```

I have a subclass that inherits from the open Kotlin class and implements the Java interface.

```
class Child : PropHolder(), Property {
  override fun getValue() = value
}
```

Running into a Platform declaration clash between:

- public open fun < get-value >(): String
- public open fun getValue(): String

I've tried:

```
class Child : PropHolder(), Property {
  override val value: String = ""
    @JvmName("getHeldValue") get() = field

  override fun getValue() = value
}
```

and:

```
class Child : PropHolder(), Property {
  @JvmName("getPropValue")
  override fun getValue() = value
}
```

But, because these are inherited methods, I can't actually override the JvmName for either.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: please give your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just added some example code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I may have run into this unresolved issue : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653

Current consensus is that there may be a KEEP written soon to explore potential options, but, no nice solution for now.